# Expo/React Native: The whole app is mirrored

Tags: ios, react-native, flexbox, expo

I'm currently developing a react native app using expo. I usually run it on my physical device (an iPhone) using the Expo app from the App Store.

But without having changed anything the app is now shown completely mirrored there. In fact, every app/snack I open on my physical device is shown mirrored. By mirrored I mean, that `flex-start` and `flex-end` are interchanged, so that a picture, that should have been on the right is shown on the left without being mirrored itself (see picture).

However, on my iPhone-simulator on my Mac everything works just right. The Expo App on my physical device has the newest version possible...

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have selected a RTL locale or language on your phone.

Comment: That‘s not the case. My phone has the locale and language settings for Germany.